# .Net Data annotation and model hierarchy

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations, model-validation

everyone! I'm confusing with implementing a piece of code to make work .net data annotation in asp.net mvc 3 with model with different required fields in several cases (6).
I have a model:

```
  public class OpportunityModel
{
    public Guid OpportunityId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[-+]?\d{1,10}(\.\d{0,4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a number")]
    public decimal? ActualValue { get; set; }  

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Product { get; set; } 

    [Display(Name = "Estimated Date")]
    public DateTime? EstimateDate { get; set; }


    public bool? Sales6ixFallDown { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Stage")]
    public Stages Sales6ixStage { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Sales6ixDateInBoard { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Sales6ixDateInCurrentStage { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Sales6ixNextAppointmentDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Sales6ixNextAppointmentDescription { get; set; }

    public int NewColumn { get; set; }

    public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is the possibility dynamically change required fiefs in it. After some googling that's impossible and came to idea to use model inheritance. I mean: I have a base model like this:

```
  public class BaseOpportunityModel
{
    public Guid OpportunityId { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal? ActualValue { get; set; }  
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }  

    public string Product { get; set; } 

    public DateTime? EstimateDate { get; set; }

    public bool? Sales6ixFallDown { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Stage")]
    public Stages Sales6ixStage { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Sales6ixDateInBoard { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Sales6ixDateInCurrentStage { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Sales6ixNextAppointmentDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Sales6ixNextAppointmentDescription { get; set; }

    public int NewColumn { get; set; }

    public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

where virtual properties are properties that may be or not a required fields. And then I have several derived model from base like this one:

```
  public class OpportunityModel0: BaseOpportunityModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[-+]?\d{1,10}(\.\d{0,4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a number")]
    public override decimal? ActualValue { get; set; }  

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
 public override string Name { get; set; }
```

}

And then I be able to use in View and Controller base model BaseOpportunityModel. But I encountered follow problem:

- Validation use annotation attributes from BaseOpportunityModel and ignore attributes in derived models.

What do I wrong? Can somebody steer me in the right direction or help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem with different reqiured validation of model with using custom RequiredIfValidator. So now I have just one model and one view. Here is code, may be some one find it useful:

**RequiredIfAttribute:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Infrastructure.Extensions
{
    public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();

        public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
        public object TargetValue { get; set; }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
        {
            this.DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
            this.TargetValue = targetValue;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
            var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
            var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.DependentProperty);

            if (field != null)
            {
                // get the value of the dependent property
                var dependentvalue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

                // compare the value against the target value
                if ((dependentvalue == null && this.TargetValue == null) ||
                    (dependentvalue != null && dependentvalue.Equals(this.TargetValue)))
                {
                    // match => means we should try validating this field
                    if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                        // validation failed - return an error
                        return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
                ValidationType = "requiredif",
            };

            string depProp = BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext);

            // find the value on the control we depend on;
            // if it's a bool, format it javascript style 
            // (the default is True or False!)
            string targetValue = (this.TargetValue ?? "").ToString();
            if (this.TargetValue.GetType() == typeof(bool))
                targetValue = targetValue.ToLower();

            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", depProp);
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("targetvalue", targetValue);

            yield return rule;
        }

        private string BuildDependentPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            // build the ID of the property
            string depProp = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty);
            // unfortunately this will have the name of the current field appended to the beginning,
            // because the TemplateInfo's context has had this fieldname appended to it. Instead, we
            // want to get the context as though it was one level higher (i.e. outside the current property,
            // which is the containing object (our Person), and hence the same level as the dependent property.
            var thisField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
            if (depProp.StartsWith(thisField))
                // strip it off again
                depProp = depProp.Substring(thisField.Length);
            return depProp;
        }
    }
}
```

**RequiredIfValidator**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Extensions
{
    public class RequiredIfValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<RequiredIfAttribute>
    {
        public RequiredIfValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RequiredIfAttribute attribute)
            : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            return base.GetClientValidationRules();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
        {
            // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
            var field = Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(Attribute.DependentProperty);

            if (field != null)
            {
                // get the value of the dependent property
                var value = field.GetValue(container, null);

                // compare the value against the target value
                if ((value == null && Attribute.TargetValue == null) ||
                    (value.Equals(Attribute.TargetValue)))
                {
                    // match => means we should try validating this field
                    if (!Attribute.IsValid(Metadata.Model))
                        // validation failed - return an error
                        yield return new ModelValidationResult { Message = ErrorMessage };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Validation**

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js" />
    /// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />

    $.validator.addMethod('requiredif',
        function (value, element, parameters) {
            var id = '#' + parameters['dependentproperty'];

            // get the target value (as a string, 
            // as that's what actual value will be)
            var targetvalue = parameters['targetvalue'];
            targetvalue =
              (targetvalue == null ? '' : targetvalue).toString();

            // get the actual value of the target control
            // note - this probably needs to cater for more 
            // control types, e.g. radios
            var control = $(id);
            var controltype = control.attr('type');
            var actualvalue =
                controltype === 'checkbox' ?
                control.is(":checked").toString() :
            //control.attr('checked').toString() :
                control.val();

            actualvalue = actualvalue.toLocaleLowerCase();

            // if the condition is true, reuse the existing 
            // required field validator functionality
            if (targetvalue === actualvalue)
                return $.validator.methods.required.call(
                  this, value, element, parameters);

            return true;
        }
    );

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'requiredif',
        ['dependentproperty', 'targetvalue'], 
        function (options) {
            options.rules['requiredif'] = {
                dependentproperty: options.params['dependentproperty'],
                targetvalue: options.params['targetvalue']
            };
            options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This tip should work in mvc 3 accroding to [THIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/10/21/bug-fixes-and-changes-in-asp-net-mvc-3-beta.aspx). One thing that may be a problem is your post action. You should specify your inherited model as param in the post action.

```
public ActionResult MyPostAction(OpportunityModel0 model)
```

If base model is param in action, validation will not work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Another thing that not work is client validation. I can fix it by specify in View OpportunityModel0, but then I need to have such view for each derived model. And this is not a good approach.